# Ionic- Angular vs Ionic - React

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

1.Which one is more easy to develop a Hybrid app , Ionic - Angular or Ionic - React?

2.Which one gives more performance?

3.Will all plugins support in both Ionic-React and Ionic- Angular?

It would be great if anyone share valuable comments and knowledge on this topic

Comment: Well, i think it would have been useful to have a discussion about the relative merits of developing Ionic apps with Angular or React, but the point gods have deemed this closed, which is a shame. I've used Angular with Ionic (a while back), but not React. I'll have to bite the bullet and try it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have some experience with Angular, you’ll find app development with Ionic an easy task since the second version of Ionic is similar to Angular in terms of structure and design.
But yes if u need performance, ionic -react may come handy.

I personally suggest Ionic-angular, Because it is very easy. High Production Value is with angular. But in terms of performance react takes an edge

Comment: Ok thank you. May i know the reason why you suggest React over Angular

Comment: I think I've suggested angular.